# AutoFac for Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5

Tags: compact-framework, autofac

Is there any support in AutoFac for Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 (basically Windows Mobile Handheld using Compact Framework 3.5). We are currently using Ninject and due to some odd threading issues we have with our web site using Ninject, we are moving over to AutoFac. But our enterprise LOB applications that run on mobile handhelds use the Compact Framework, which is supported by Ninject.

If there is no AutoFac support I might stick to using Ninject for the compact framework and come up with some way to abstract between the two. Ideally I would love it if it can be supported, because our Windows Forms client apps share most of their code with the handheld versions. Or maybe I will just stick to Ninject for the Windows Forms code as it works fine there, and change to AutoFac for the web site.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [using the CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) for injection, which would allow you to use AutoFac or Ninject (or several other options).  It doesn't specifically have a CF build, but I added support for it in [my own IoC project which supports the CF](http://ioc.codeplex.com/) and it was really straightforward, so I suspect that getting it to work with the CF version of Ninject should be easy as well.

Comment: That is a reasonable option that would allow me to use Autofac for the Windows forms code, and Ninject for the CF code. If I cannot find a way to get a native build of Autofac I might give that a try.